# @ConditionalOnBean(KafkaTemplate.class) crashes entire application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-annotations

I have a `Spring boot` application that consumes data from `Kafka` topic and send email notifications with a data received from `Kafka`,

```
@Bean
public EmailService emailService() {
    return new EmailServiceImpl(getJavaMailSender());
}
```

it works perfectly,
but after I added `@ConditionalOnBean`:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(KafkaTemplate.class)
public EmailService emailService() {
    return new EmailServiceImpl(getJavaMailSender());
}
```

application failed to start:

> required a bean of type 'com.acme.EmailService' that could not be
> found.

And I can't find any explanation, how it is possible, because `KafkaTemplate` bean automatically created by `Spring` in `KafkaAutoConfiguration` class.

Could you please give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html):

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been
> processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is
> strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration
> classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another
> auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs
> after.

This documentation clearly says what might be wrong here. I understand `KafkaTemplateConfiguration` creates the `KafkaTemplate.class`. But it may not be added in the bean context while the condition was being checked. Try to use autoconfiguration for `KafkaTemplate` or make sure the ordering of different configuration classes so that you can have the guarantee of having the `KafkaTemplate` in bean registry before that conditional check.

Comment: To add to this: If you are making your own autoconfiguration add `@AutoConfigureAfter(KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)`